# "Together with my three fellow students (,) I am/we are"

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, syntactic-analysis, personal-pronouns

Which of the following sentences is correct?

1. Together with my three fellow students, **we are** most interested in hiring the villa.
2. Together with my three fellow students **we are** most interested in hiring the villa.
3. Together with my three fellow students, **I am** most interested in hiring the villa.
4. Together with my three fellow students **I am** most interested in hiring the villa.

I think the first sentence is correct, and this is not homework.

Comment: Which one do you think is correct? Please at least attempt to do your homework before bringing it to us.

Comment: I think the first sentence is correct, and this is not homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say "My three fellow students and I are most interested in renting the villa."

Here it is clear that "my three fellow students and I" is a group, and you use the plural.

You can test your sentences by moving thing around. "I, together with my three fellow students, am interested..." This is fine, but sounds archaic or stilted.

If you try this with your first version, you will realize that it is unclear. "We, together with my..."??